# Implicit Differentiation: Find $dy/dx$ for $y = (1 + x\ln(x))^{\tan(2x)}$ when $x = 1$

Tags: calculus

Find $dy/dx$ for $y = (1 + x\ln(x))^{\tan(2x)}$ when $x = 1$

Now, I was thinking about taking the natural log of both sides to get:

$\ln(y) = \tan(2x)\ln(1 + x\ln(x))$;

However, differentiating we get:

$(dy/dx)/y = 2\sec2(2x)\ln(1 + x\ln(x)) + \tan(2x)\ldots$ a lot of stuff.

My point is that there is a $y$ term left over in the equation and we do not have a value for $y$ At this point I am stuck.

Comment: Multiply both sides by $y$, and you have an expression for $y'$ in terms of $x$ and $y$

Comment: So far I have: dy/dx = ( 2sec^2(x)ln(1 + xln(x)) + tan(2x)( (ln(x)+1)/(1+xln(x)) ) ) * (1+xln(x))^{tan(2x)}.  This seems...really long. Is this correct? If so, I plug in x=1 and done.

Comment: I have updated the post to LaTeX, please see that the edits are correct.

Comment: Edits look great. I'm sorry that you had to fix my poor formatting. I will try to format better next time.

Comment: It's fine! No need to apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Ok.  So, first we differentiate.  Taking $\ln$ of both sides is a good idea:
$$y=\left(1+x\ln(x)\right)^{\tan(2x)}$$
$$\ln y = \tan(2x)\ln\left(1+x\ln(x)\right)$$
Using implicit differentiation:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{1}{y} = \tan(2x)\left[\frac{d}{dx}\ln\left(1+x\ln(x)\right)\right] + \ln\left(1+x\ln(x)\right)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\tan(2x)$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{1}{y} = \tan(2x)\left(\frac{1+\ln(x)}{1+x\ln(x)}\right) + \ln\left(1+x\ln(x)\right)2\sec^2(2x)$$

Solving for $\frac{dy}{dx}$:
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = y\left(\tan(2x)\left(\frac{1+\ln(x)}{1+x\ln(x)}\right) + \ln\left(1+x\ln(x)\right)2\sec^2(2x)\right)$$

**Oh no!  We have a $y$ variable, but we don't have its value!  What do we do?**

(This is where I thought the original question picked up.) Having a $y$ left over in the equation is not a problem.  We know that:
$$y=\left(1+x\ln(x)\right)^{\tan(2x)}$$

So, when $\color{red}{x = 1}$:
$$\begin{align}
y&=\left(1+\color{red}{1}\ln(\color{red}{1})\right)^{\tan(2\cdot\color{red}{1})}\\
&=1^{\tan(2)}\\
&=1
\end{align}$$

Thus, we plug in $\color{red}{x = 1}, \quad \color{blue}{y = 1}$:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx} &= \color{blue}{1}\left(\tan(2\cdot\color{red}{1})\left(\frac{1+\ln(\color{red}{1})}{1+\color{red}{1}\ln(\color{red}{1})}\right) + \ln\left(1+\color{red}{1}\ln(\color{red}{1})\right)2\sec^2(2\cdot\color{red}{1})\right)\\
&= \color{blue}{1}\left(\tan(2)\left(\frac{1}{1}\right) + \ln(1)\cdot2\sec^2(2)\right)\\
&= \tan(2) + 0\\
&= \boxed{\tan(2)}
\end{align}$$

Comment: But... you didn't do any differentiation. It asked for dy/dx.

Comment: @Ozera Sorry--I thought that your question was "we have a $y$ term left over after differentiation, and what do we do with it now?"  I'll edit to be more clear.

Comment: Ah this makes sense. Sorry for the silly question. Thank you!

Comment: @Ozera No problem! (And, no need to apologize--I've asked my classmates and teachers many questions that were quite trivial once I knew the answer, but appear very difficult beforehand.  Don't worry about any question being "too silly.")  `:)`